# pip not found on virtual environment

Tags: python, django, pip

I created a virtual environment which called "hekim_venv". But when I try the install django in it, it gives "pip not found error". When I check the pip location there are no pip. When I check pip3 it indicates homebrew location. So there are no pip for venv's.

How can I install libraries in virtual env? I can not understand and figure out the configuration.

```
(hekim_venv) cucal@CANER-MacBook-Air dentist_project % pip install django
zsh: command not found: pip

(hekim_venv) cucal@CANER-MacBook-Air dentist_project % pip3 install django
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: django in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.4.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from django) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from django) (0.4.2)
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621

(hekim_venv) cucal@CANER-MacBook-Air dentist_project % which pip
pip not found

(hekim_venv) cucal@CANER-MacBook-Air dentist_project % which pip3
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
```

Comment: Thank you for editing. How did you create the virtual environment?

Comment: I used "virtualenv -p python3 hekim_venv" command. Environment created successfully, no problem. I think I need to add pip to PATH

Comment: I haven't used `virtualenv` in ages (these days I rely on Poetry or the built-in `venv` module; before that I used `pew` and `virtualenvwrapper`), but it looks like `virtualenv` should include `pip` by default, assuming it's available in the Python environment you're building from. Does your default `python3` environment include `pip`?

Comment: I solved with using venv. It includes default pip as you said. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I used venv module instead of virtualenv and problem solved.